# Easy mount hdd from remote computer

Tags: mount, hard-disk

I've got a computer with an SSD with Linux Mint installed and a bunch of HDD's. When in the file-browser I click one of the HHD's they get mounted in /media, which is fine for me. However I need to put files on thoses drives remotely. I'm using WinScp and that works fine, however only when the drives are already mounted, so I have to physically access the Linux computer and click on the HDD-icons.

So my question is: is there a command to mount all the drives to /media, like what's happening when I click on them in the file browser? Then I can use PuTTY to send that command.

Thanks

Comment: If they are listed in `/etc/fstab/` then `mount -a` will mount all listed.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. I don't seem to have a directory /etc/fstab, but I do have an (empty) /etc/fstab.d

Comment: bdowning is right, that what you are looking for is an fstab entry, so things automatically mount where you want them.  Here's a post to help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/303497/adding-an-entry-to-fstab